# Как при пустом значении в окне ввода выводить окно с сообщением(Tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть программа на python, в ней надо вводить некоторые данные о пользователе. Эти данные не должны быть null, то есть в поле ввода хоть что-то, но должно быть написанно. Как устроить проверку этих полей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пример проверки при добавлении данных через консоль**

Это обезопасит вас **только** от значения 'Null', но не защитит от пробелов " " и других запрещённых символов

```py
a = input("Введите значение: ")

if a == '': # В данном случае переменную 'a' можно заменить на значение из Edit
   print('Вы ничего не ввели') #Вывод ошибки так же можно реализовать по другому
else:
   print('Вы ввели:' + a)
```

Comment: Теперь только всё это в окно сообщения вывести осталось